# Updating in ms access using vb.net issue about primary key being -1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access-2007

I am making a program where I click a cell in a data grid and it passes the selected string to another dataset in another form. After it, the form with a dataset has its ID (the primary key) value to -1 which I think is the reason why I encounter mistakes in updating

The errors I encountered is concurrency issue and not null

Please help. I really need it

Comment: It will be useful to provide more details about your code and the tests you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table in Access with a primary key of type `AutoNumber`, the corresponding column in a .NET `DataTable` will behave as you see, i.e. it will generate temporary PK values seeded at -1 and incrementing by -1.  The reason for that is to ensure that no value generated will be the same as a PK value already in the database.  You can use that PK as a foreign key in your app to create child records.

When you save the parent record to your database, it generates a final PK value and that is what gets saved, not your temporary value.  At that point, if you are using that temporary value anywhere, it's up to you to get the final value from the database and then propagate it to wherever it's needed.  Normally, it would be propagated automatically via a `DataRelation` to one or more other `DataTable` objects in the same `DataSet`.

I would say that your first mistake is using that temporary PK outside of the same `DataSet`.  If you need to use the PK elsewhere then you should be saving the data first, getting the final PK and using that.  If you can't do that then the records should only be within the same `DataSet`.

You should check out my thread on retrieving `AutoNumber` values from Access and propagating them using a `DataRelation`:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert

Here's the crux of the code from the example with a typed `DataSet`:

```
''' <summary>
''' Handles the RowUpdated event of the parent adapter.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender">
''' The adapter that saved the row.
''' </param>
''' <param name="e">
''' The data for the event.
''' </param>
''' <remarks>
''' This event handler is used to retrieve an auto-generated ID from the database after a row is inserted and update the corresponding row in the local data set.
''' </remarks>
Private Sub parentAdapter_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    'We are only interested in new records.
    If e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
        'Get the last ID auto-generated by the database.
        Dim lastAutoNumber = Me.parentAdapter.GetLastAutoNumber().Value

        'Update the ID of the local row.
        DirectCast(e.Row, ParentChildDataSet.ParentRow).ParentID = lastAutoNumber
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Handles the RowUpdated event of the child adapter.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender">
''' The adapter that saved the row.
''' </param>
''' <param name="e">
''' The data for the event.
''' </param>
''' <remarks>
''' This event handler is used to retrieve an auto-generated ID from the database after a row is inserted and update the corresponding row in the local data set.
''' </remarks>
Private Sub childAdapter_RowUpdated(sender As Object, e As OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
    'We are only interested in new records.
    If e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert Then
        'Get the last ID auto-generated by the database.
        Dim lastAutoNumber = Me.childAdapter.GetLastAutoNumber().Value

        'Update the ID of the local row.
        DirectCast(e.Row, ParentChildDataSet.ChildRow).ChildID = lastAutoNumber
    End If
End Sub
```

`GetLastAutoNumber` is a custom scalar query added to the table adapter in the designer and this is the SQL code:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```